# What information depicts the quantitative difference between two large given files of the same size?

Tags: python, linux, bash, statistics, hexdump

Usually, in order to find how two binary files are different, I use diff and hexdump tools. But in some situations if two large binary files of the same size are given, I would like to see only their quantitative differences, like number of regions of differences, cumulative difference.

Example: 2 Files A and B. They have 2 diff regions, and their cumulative difference is 
6c-a3 + 6c-11 + 6f-6e + 20-22.

```
File A = 48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57
File B = 48 65 a3 11 6e 2c 22 57
              |--------|  |--|
                 reg 1   reg 2
```

How can I get such information using standard GNU tools and Bash or should I better use a simple Python script? Other statistics about how 2 files are different can also be useful, but I don't know what else and how can be measured? Entropy difference? Variance difference?

Comment: What's wrong with the `cmp` program you already have in linux? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_(Unix).  Also, if the files are different sizes (or the compared regions are different sizes), what's the result?

Comment: Your definition of "cumulative difference" would imply that the cumulative difference between `00 ff` and `ff 00` is 0.  Is this intended?

Comment: As a more general note:  Without specifying the purpose it is rather meaningless to ask for other "difference measures".  You could consider the two files as vectors (of bytes) and use any finite-dimensional vector norm.

Comment: @sven 1.it depends, sometimes I need it. But you always can just abs() or square the differencies 2.The purpose is to have some statistics about quantitative differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everything but the regions thing you can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/). Something like this (untested):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.fromfile("file A", dtype="uint8")
b = np.fromfile("file B", dtype="uint8")

# Compute the number of bytes that are different
different_bytes = np.sum(a != b)

# Compute the sum of the differences
difference = np.sum(a - b)

# Compute the sum of the absolute value of the differences
absolute_difference = np.sum(np.abs(a - b))

# In some cases, the number of bits that have changed is a better
# measurement of change. To compute it we make a lookup array where 
# bitcount_lookup[byte] == number_of_1_bits_in_byte (so
# bitcount_lookup[0:16] == [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4])
bitcount_lookup = np.array(
    [bin(i).count("1") for i in range(256)], dtype="uint8")

# Numpy allows using an array as an index. ^ computes the XOR of
# each pair of bytes. The result is a byte with a 1 bit where the
# bits of the input differed, and a 0 bit otherwise.
bit_diff_count = np.sum(bitcount_lookup[a ^ b])
```

I couldn't find a numpy function for computing the regions, but just write your own using `a != b` as input, it shouldn't be hard. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619413/efficiently-finding-the-interval-with-non-zeros-in-scipy-numpy-in-python) question for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that springs to mind is to hack a bit on a binary diffing algorithm. E.g. [a python implementation of the rsync algorithm](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577518-rsync-algorithm/). Starting from that should relatively easily get you a list of block ranges where the files differ, and then do whatever statistics you want to do on those blocks.